# Url maliciosas en mongodb

Tags: mongodb, angular6

Tengo una duda sobre bbdd y url maliciosas.
Tengo una aplicación en MEAN STACK, y estoy un poco paranoica, ya que el otro día, inserté en el index, el link 
de fontawesome, y de repente apareció  Ad.  doubleclick.   net en la pagina que tenía abierta... 
No se como llegó, estaba trabajando en LOCALHOST, era la primera vez en mi vida que me pasaba, quite el link, "limpiè" la aplicación, y todo perfecto,

Ahora viene mi psicosis...

En mi aplicación  quiero que los usuario pueda insertar 
varios enlaces a donde ellos quieran

Ejemplo
Mi bbdd seria así

- titulo "curso udemy"
- Url "***aquí iría la url del curso***"

Mi pregunta el la siguiente

¿Como puedo evitar que al insertar la url, no sea una url maliciosa?,
 rollo...

1. Ad.  doubleclick.   net

Comment: Interesante pregunta, sin embargo no te podría dar una respuesta "correcta" ya que me parece que puede haber más de una solución. No podemos evitar que un usuario escriba lo que le salga del alma en los input de nuestras app. Podemos asegurarnos que no son bots usando servicios de `captcha`. En cuanto a lo que planteas, puedes usar un filtro. Si lo que vas a hacer es almacenar urls de Udemy, puedes verificar que la url escrita empiece con: `https://www.udemy.com`. Como ves es una solución básica. Saludos.